# Eclipse, MinGW, Freeglut undefined reference

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, linker-errors, freeglut

I've been trying to compile this OpenGL tutorial (originally purposed for Visual Studio) but I keep having 'undefined reference' errors. The compiler output is as follows:

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -o OpenGLTutorial.exe "src\\main.o" "src\\Camera.o" -lglew32 -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lfreeglut 
src\main.o: In function `Z6InitGLiPPc':
C:\Users\jordanrich\Documents\programming\C++\GameDev\OpenGLTutorial\Debug/../src/main.cpp:75: undefined reference to `glutInit'
C:\Users\jordanrich\Documents\programming\C++\GameDev\OpenGLTutorial\Debug/../src/main.cpp:76: undefined reference to `glutSetOption'
C:\Users\jordanrich\Documents\programming\C++\GameDev\OpenGLTutorial\Debug/../src/main.cpp:77: undefined reference to `glutGet'
C:\Users\jordanrich\Documents\programming\C++\GameDev\OpenGLTutorial\Debug/../src/main.cpp:78: undefined reference to `glutGet'
C:\Users\jordanrich\Documents\programming\C++\GameDev\OpenGLTutorial\Debug/../src/main.cpp:80: undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'
C:\Users\jordanrich\Documents\programming\C++\GameDev\OpenGLTutorial\Debug/../src/main.cpp:82: undefined reference to `glutInitContextVersion'
C:\Users\jordanrich\Documents\programming\C++\GameDev\OpenGLTutorial\Debug/../src/main.cpp:83: undefined reference to `glutInitContextProfile'
C:\Users\jordanrich\Documents\programming\C++\GameDev\OpenGLTutorial\Debug/../src/main.cpp:84: undefined reference to `glutInitContextFlags'
C:\Users\jordanrich\Documents\programming\C++\GameDev\OpenGLTutorial\Debug/../src/main.cpp:86: undefined reference to `glutInitWindowPosition'
C:\Users\jordanrich\Documents\programming\C++\GameDev\OpenGLTutorial\Debug/../src/main.cpp:87: undefined reference to `glutInitWindowSize'
C:\Users\jordanrich\Documents\programming\C++\GameDev\OpenGLTutorial\Debug/../src/main.cpp:89: undefined reference to `glutCreateWindow'
C:\Users\jordanrich\Documents\programming\C++\GameDev\OpenGLTutorial\Debug/../src/main.cpp:91: undefined reference to `glutIdleFunc'
C:\Users\jordanrich\Documents\programming\C++\GameDev\OpenGLTutorial\Debug/../src/main.cpp:92: undefined reference to `glutDisplayFunc'
C:\Users\jordanrich\Documents\programming\C++\GameDev\OpenGLTutorial\Debug/../src/main.cpp:93: undefined reference to `glutKeyboardFunc'
C:\Users\jordanrich\Documents\programming\C++\GameDev\OpenGLTutorial\Debug/../src/main.cpp:94: undefined reference to `glutKeyboardUpFunc'
C:\Users\jordanrich\Documents\programming\C++\GameDev\OpenGLTutorial\Debug/../src/main.cpp:95: undefined reference to `glutSpecialFunc'
C:\Users\jordanrich\Documents\programming\C++\GameDev\OpenGLTutorial\Debug/../src/main.cpp:96: undefined reference to `glutSpecialUpFunc'
C:\Users\jordanrich\Documents\programming\C++\GameDev\OpenGLTutorial\Debug/../src/main.cpp:97: undefined reference to `glutMouseFunc'
C:\Users\jordanrich\Documents\programming\C++\GameDev\OpenGLTutorial\Debug/../src/main.cpp:98: undefined reference to `glutMotionFunc'
C:\Users\jordanrich\Documents\programming\C++\GameDev\OpenGLTutorial\Debug/../src/main.cpp:99: undefined reference to `glutReshapeFunc'
src\main.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\jordanrich\Documents\programming\C++\GameDev\OpenGLTutorial\Debug/../src/main.cpp:236: undefined reference to `glutMainLoop'
src\main.o: In function `Z9ReshapeGLii':
C:\Users\jordanrich\Documents\programming\C++\GameDev\OpenGLTutorial\Debug/../src/main.cpp:249: undefined reference to `glutPostRedisplay'
src\main.o: In function `Z9DisplayGLv':
C:\Users\jordanrich\Documents\programming\C++\GameDev\OpenGLTutorial\Debug/../src/main.cpp:262: undefined reference to `glutSwapBuffers'
src\main.o: In function `Z6IdleGLv':
C:\Users\jordanrich\Documents\programming\C++\GameDev\OpenGLTutorial\Debug/../src/main.cpp:278: undefined reference to `glutPostRedisplay'
src\main.o: In function `Z10KeyboardGLhii':
C:\Users\jordanrich\Documents\programming\C++\GameDev\OpenGLTutorial\Debug/../src/main.cpp:313: undefined reference to `glutLeaveMainLoop'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

21:39:05 Build Finished (took 1s.154ms)
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?
If you need any more information to help answer the question just ask.

Edit (Some additional info):
As you can see from the compiler output I have linked the library that these functions require and the compiler does not complain that it could not find said library. Also I placed the freeglut dll into the binary folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I added more info to the question to show that it is not, in fact, a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## This problem was apparently mainly due to user error and was completely circumstantial. I'm posting this for the people of the future who might have this problem.

In my header file I defined FREEGLUT_STATIC. After changing this to another variable, the linker no longer produced errors. Though I can't actually check -- very easily at least -- somewhere in my freeglut library this variable was used in an ifndef statement to determine whether freeglut needed to be linked (in case it was already linked).